# My code for face detection using opencv python is show error message given below

Tags: python, detection, opencv

On execution of my python code using openCV for face detection, the interpreter throws following  errors:

File "c:\Users\hp\Desktop\face detection\sample.py", line 8, in  gray = cv2.cvtColor (img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.3) C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-bui 1d-s03wleBq\opencv\modules\ingproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor"

My code I wrote:

```py
import cv2

#Load the cascade

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

# Read the input image

img= cv2.imread('terry.jpg')

# Convert into grayscale

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#Detect faces

faces=face_cascade.detectMultiscale(gray, 1.1, 4)

# Draw rectangle around the faces

for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
    

cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 0, 0), 2)

# Display the output

cv2.imshow('img', img)

cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: does the image terry.jpg exist (and its readable/accessable)?

Comment: Other note use `detectMultiScale` instead of `detectMultiscale`  (i.e. Capital S in scale)